# GKScore rank is always 0

Tags: ios, game-center

I'm nearing completion of my first app that utilizes (and requires) Game Center. I'm not doing achievements, just a high score system. I have everything plugged in, my app is registered in iTunesConnect with Game Center enabled, and when I log a high score it appears in the list as it should.

The one thing that isn't working is "rank". In the completion block of `[GKScore reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:]`, the rank property of my GKScore object is always 0, even if the user got a new high score.

For example, in my app when I run:

```
GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"1"];
scoreReporter.value = 2200003; // test value
[scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

    if (error != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"An error occured reporting the Game Center score: %@", error);
    }

    NSLog(@"Score: %@", scoreReporter);
    NSLog(@"Score: %d", scoreReporter.rank);
}];
```

...no error occurs and the output is:

```
Score: <GKScore: 0x361a3c0><0x361a3c0> player=G:1127411264 rank=0 date=2012-02-04 22:19:52 +0000 value=2200002 formattedValue=(null) context=(null)
Score: 0
```

Is there maybe something I'm missing in iTunesConnect? Will rank start working once I leave the sandbox? Any pointers in the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no mistake in your code. The value of rank always 0 if you just create GKScore object. It is only valid on score objects received from Game Center.
Please read this doc:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKScore_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: This is correct. I had, of course, read that documentation, but for some reason had misinterpreted "The value of this property is undefined on a newly initialized GKScore object. It is only valid on score objects received from Game Center." to mean that rank would be filled in the completion block. It of course means that if you created the GKScore, rank will always be 0. The question still remains: "how do you get the rank of a score you just posted?" I will perhaps do another question asking that specific question.

Answer (score 1):

laxcat, You cannot get a rank of just added score immediatly, but after period of time, you can perform request to get user rank:

```
GKLeaderboard *lb = [[[GKLeaderboard alloc] init] autorelease];
lb.category = @"YOURLeaderBoardID";
lb. timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeToday;
[lb loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) 
                                {
                                     GKLocalPlayer *lp = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
                                     for (GKScore* score in scores)
                                     {
                                         if ([score.playerID sEqualToString:lp.playerID])
                                         {
                                             NSLog(@"rank = %d", score.rank);
                                         }
                                     }
                                }];
```

Please try this, and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: playerID is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your integer onto a `int64_t`. In Objective-C terms, that's a `LongLong`. You can change this:

```
GKScore *myScore = [[GKScore alloc]initWithCategory:@"1"];
myScore.value = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:score] longLongValue]; //score should be of type int
```

Answer (score 0):

**OBJ-C With ARC enabled - getting rank for player in Leaderboard**
There is no need to loop through scores, simply access directly via [YourAllocatedLeaderBoard].localPlayerScore.rank (in completion handler)

```
GKLeaderboard *leaderBoard = [[GKLeaderboard alloc]init];
    [leaderBoard setIdentifier:@"yourLeaderboardID"];
    [leaderBoard setTimeScope:GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime];

    [leaderBoard loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<GKScore *> * _Nullable scores, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"RANK %d",(int)leaderBoard.localPlayerScore.rank);

        }else{
            NSLog(@"*error* %@",error.localizedDescription);

        }
    }];

    leaderBoard = nil;
```